# How to get the folder path using folder name from the system in Python using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to get the complete folder path by searching with the particular folder name using python

**Input**

***example input foldername***:  Myfile_data

I want to search with the folder name in entire sys and get where the particular folder is located

***expected Output***

example complete folder path:C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Myfile_data

please help out with this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This will take a lot of time to process, as it has to go through all the system to search for files

Comment: Is there any possible way to get the folderpath using foldername

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This searches the entire OS for files or directories.

```
import os, re

def find_files(filename, search_path, files_or_dirs='files', is_regex=False):
  result = []

  # Walking top-down from the root
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_path):
    if files_or_dirs == 'files':
      for file in files:
        if re.search(filename, file) if is_regex else file == filename:
          result.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    else:
      for dir in dirs:
        if re.search(filename, dir) if is_regex else dir == filename:
          result.append(os.path.join(root, dir))

  return result
```

To use it, just do:

```
results = find_files('file.txt', 'C:\\', 'files')
print(results)

# will print something like
# ['C:\example\file.txt', ...]
```

To search directories instead of files, do this:

```
results = find_files('mydir', 'C:\\', 'dirs')
print(results)

# will print something like
# ['C:\example\mydir\', ...]
```

To search files with a regex, do this:

```
results = find_files(r'.+\.txt', 'C:\\', 'files', is_regex=True)
print(results)

# will print something like
# ['C:\example\file.txt', 'C:\Users\DELL\example.txt', ...]
```

---

This searches the entire OS for files or directories but returns a generator, which basically means you can use it in a `for ... in ...` loop to get live results without waiting for the search to finish.

```
def find_files_gen(filename, search_path, files_or_dirs='files'):
  # Walking top-down from the root
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_path):
    if files_or_dirs == 'files':
      for file in files:
        if file == filename:
          yield os.path.join(root, file)
    else:
      for dir in dirs:
        if dir == filename:
          yield os.path.join(root, dir)
```

To use this method, like this:

```
for result in find_files_gen('file.txt', 'C:\\', 'files'): # or 'dirs'
    print(result)
```